# Change the level of the significance p values in tab_model from sjPlot (R)

Tags: r, sjplot

I am using the `tab_model` function to report the results of multiple fixed effects regression. I used the argument `p.style = "scientific_stars"` to report the statistical significance of the results. However, the values reported are only `* p<0.05 ** p<0.01 *** p<0.001`. I would like to also report a 90% confidence level (p<0.10). Is it possible to customize the significance level reported in `tab_model`?

Sample code:

```
library(fixest)
library(sjPlot)
reg <- feols(mpg ~ vs + wt + disp | gear + am, data = mtcars)

table <- tab_model(reg, auto.label = TRUE, show.se = TRUE, show.ci = FALSE, p.style = "scientific_stars",title = "Table A: ", dv.labels = c("Outcome"), pred.labels = c("IV1", "IV2", "Control"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the p-value level using the `p.threshold` command and the 90% CI using the `show.ci` command (which is defaulted to 95% CI):

```
tab_model(reg, auto.label = TRUE, show.se = TRUE, 
          show.ci = 0.90, # 90% CI
          p.threshold = c(0.527, 0.191, 0.00001), #arbitrary p values
          p.style = "scientific_stars",
          title = "Table A: ", dv.labels = c("Outcome"), 
          pred.labels = c("IV1", "IV2", "Control"))
```

[image]